# SharePoint 2010 People Picker on 2013 sites

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, peoplepicker

I have a code to generate custom form on 2010, that will generate form control based on the field type. I used the same code in 2013 I am getting the 2010 People Picker field including the resolve and search options. There is not auto complete options also. Is there ay specific property I need to set to convert the field to 2013 type field.

Note: OOB form its working as expected 2013 PP field shows.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint:ClientPeoplePicker instead SharePoint:FormField

Complete solution :
[Solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/9ea38626-8f19-4e75-9d25-6f3eff25f3b5/autocomplete-for-people-picker-field-is-not-working-in-custom-list-form?forum=sharepointcustomization)